# performance issue in jointjs when more component

Tags: jointjs

I have to use jointJs for building workflow diagram.
So how much performance will affect in ie browser when there are more then 200 component(includes arrows, nodes,bozes ) on same page ?

Answer (score 1):

As you may know there is a demo application named Rappid [here](http://www.jointjs.com/rappid/)

You can test your performance requirements there.

I have tested the performance with ~150 components and 1 link between 2components and there was no performance issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it for more than 200 nodes, but there are problems like if you want to add some description near every block at the same time it will hang for few minutes. But if you are doing operations in batches then it will be ok. There are problems if you want to hide 100 nodes together. I am doing these type of tasks using jQuery. I am using it for very complex use case for more than 500 nodes including nodes, arrows and other helper components. Tell me your exact requirement and I will be able to tell you if it will work or not.

Comment: For 100 nodes its $scope.graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(graphJson)) function is taking around 5 seconds and for 200 around 10 seconds. After loading graph if you want to show desc to each node it will again take few seconds to load these new nodes.

Comment: Or tell me specific question you want to ask?